# Pandas remove duplicate with special condition

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

Suppose I have this df:

```
Day Id   Value
7   111  a
6   111  a 
5   111  a
4   111  b
3   111  b
2   111  a
1   111  a
6   222  a
5   222  a
4   222  b
3   222  b
2   222  b
1   222  b
```

I want to remove duplicates to get the result like this:  (only keep the row everytime the value switches)

```
Day Id   Value
5   111  a
3   111  b
1   111  a
5   222  a
1   222  b
```

I tried: df = df.drop_duplicates(['Id', 'Value'], keep = 'last')

```
Day Id   Value
3   111  b
1   111  a
5   222  a
1   222  b
```

As you can see I'm missing "5   111  a".  Please let me know how I can fix this.  Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
columns = ['Id','Value']
df[np.any(df[columns].shift(-1) != df[columns], axis=1)]
#    Day   Id Value
#2     5  111     a
#4     3  111     b
#6     1  111     a
#8     5  222     a
#12    1  222     b
```

Answer (score 1):

Slightly more procedural approach, but DYZ's is impressive nonetheless.

```
df = pd.read_clipboard()
df['flag'] = df['Id'].astype(str) + "|" + df['Value']
df

    Day Id  Value   flag
0   7   111 a   111|a
1   6   111 a   111|a
2   5   111 a   111|a
3   4   111 b   111|b
4   3   111 b   111|b
5   2   111 a   111|a
6   1   111 a   111|a
7   6   222 a   222|a
8   5   222 a   222|a
9   4   222 b   222|b
10  3   222 b   222|b
11  2   222 b   222|b
12  1   222 b   222|b


to_keep = []

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    try:
        next_val = df.iloc[index+1]['flag']        
        if row['flag'] != next_val:
            to_keep.append(row)
    except IndexError:
        to_keep.append(row)

pd.DataFrame.from_records(to_keep)

    Day Id  Value   flag
0   5   111 a   111|a
1   3   111 b   111|b
2   1   111 a   111|a
3   5   222 a   222|a
4   1   222 b   222|b
```